# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \Biggl(\ln\biggl(\Bigl({x-1\over x+1}\Bigr)^2\biggr)*x-2*\ln|x^2-1|\Biggr)$

Tags: limits

I have a limit problem I can't solve.

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim\limits_{x \to 1^-} \Biggl(\ln\biggl(\Bigl({x-1\over x+1}\Bigr)^2\biggr)*x-2*\ln|x^2-1|\Biggr)$$

I think I need to do something with "x+1" or "x-1". I can factor the second term:

$$2*ln|(x+1)*(x-1)|$$

But I don't know what to do after that. Does somebody know a way to solve this limit / or can somebody give me a hint on how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can get rid of the absolute value noting that $x \to 1-0$ means that $x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your limit can be written as

$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}\Bigl(2x\ln(1-x)-2x\ln(x+1)-2\ln(1-x)-2\ln(x+1)\Bigr)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 1^-}\Bigl(-2(1-x)\ln(1-x)-2(x+1)\ln(x+1)\Bigr)$$
$$=0 - 4\ln(2) = \ln(\frac{1}{16})$$